# wlp2s0 getting two IP addresses, Internet not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, arch-linux, dhcp

I am trying to connect to my D-Link router, which is **NOT** a DHCP server, but some other router on the network is (192.168.0.200).

I get an IP address from the DHCP at 192.168.0.200, but I am getting one more IP address, from different subnet (192.168.2.0/24). I am using Arch Linux with KDE. This happens even when I use static IP configuration by manually assigning IP address.

[image: Screenshot showing ip addresses]

I am unable to connect to the internet. Please help!

Edit:
Added output of `ip route`

Also, I don't use dhclient. (Some Arch Linux thing - Pardon me if I'm wrong)

[image]

Comment: `ip link set wlp2s0 down` -> `ip link set wlp2s0 up`, and then you can try to connect with **nmcli**

Comment: Yup. Did all that, but still no luck.

Comment: Do you edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Comment: No. I didn't edit "/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf". The file doesn't even exist in my system.

Comment: create /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf and edit it like in my answer.

Comment: I did "sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.200 wlp2s0" and internet is working now.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having two IP address shouldn't prevent you from accessing the Internet.

For the two IP, the intriguing part is that the one supposed to be DHCP is not dynamic.
Can you provide the result of `ip route`?

Another thing you can seek is the presence of multiple dhclient instances, or multiple network manager. Can you check what dhcp dialog occurs on your machine?

(I would have put this as a comment, but I can't...)

Comment: "For the two IP, the intriguing part is that the one supposed to be DHCP is not dynamic" - I have said in my question that  "This happens even when I use static IP configuration by manually assigning IP address." In the screenshot, it is a manually assigned IP, hence no lease time

Answer (score 0):

I use Debian, and my configuration looks like this:

/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
network={
         ssid="BL250"
         psk=""
        }
```

then, I just type:

```
ip link set wlp2s0 down
ip link set wlp2s0 up
nmcli d wifi connect BL250
```